# Are Python "multiprocessing" servers on the Internet insecure?

Tags: python, security, multiprocessing

I read somewhere that Python's `multiprocessing` uses Pickle internally and that Pickle data coming from unathenticated hosts isn't safe to be used. Assuming that I'm running a `multiprocessing` server on the Internet guarded by a weak password, can the attacker automatically run arbitrary code when the password is broken?

Comment: try: [`pickle.loads("cos\nsystem\n(S'ls ~'\ntR.")`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10282444/4279)

Comment: Thanks @J.F.Sebastian, but it doesn't sound like an answer yet - I don't know how multiprocessing protocol works from the security perspective.

Comment: that is why I've posted it as a comment and not an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If the attacker can send pickle-based payload decoded by the server the attacker can run arbitrary code on the server.

[See warning here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#connection-objects).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using `multiprocessing.connection` and `AF_INET` family:

Multiprocessing listener are bound to the host specified in the address by default.

So

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener
with Listener(("0.0.0.0", 5678)) as listener:
    while True:
        with listener.accept() as connection:
            print(connection.recv())
```

in this example, it will accept a connection from any host.

However if `0.0.0.0` is replaced with `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`, it will only accept connections from localhost.

With proper firewall configuration and no port forwarding, you should be safe.  [dns - How secure is binding to localhost in order to prevent remote connections? - Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86773/how-secure-is-binding-to-localhost-in-order-to-prevent-remote-connections)

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing an internet service or web app in Python, incoming data should *always* be inspected (and cleaned up or rejected if necessary) at the point of entry. *Under no circumstance* should it be processed by the application as-is.

This is mostly unrelated to multiprocessing; It's not just pickling/unpickling that is dangerous here. If you look at the [top-10 of web app vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10) you will see that **injection** (basically interpreting incoming data without inspection) is the *most common* problem in web apps.

This might be a somewhat contrived example, but nonetheless a good illustration of the problem;

[image: database trouble]

Additionally it would be a good idea to isolate the web app as much as possible. I would suggest running it in a FreeBSD [`jail`](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/jails.html) or maybe a docker container on Linux.

Comment: Good point about jailing the application. The question I asked was a bit different though - I wanted to know if multiprocessing is inherently insecure when authentication is broken - i.e. just being able to connect is enough to execute arbitrary code.

Comment: @d33tah My point was that it is not multiprocessing that creates the insecurety, but the use of unsanitized input. The possible abuse of pickling which affects multiprocessing is just *one* of the *many possible* injection attacks.

Comment: And my question is about whether you actually need to make your application insecure or whether the fact that the password is broken automatically makes it so.

Comment: The latter , if only the password allows access. Of course in the worst case even the password mechanism can be used as an injection attack.