# Unable to send a dictionary to RabbitMQ (unhashable type: 'slice')

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, rabbitmq

I want to send a messge to RabbitMQ in a  dictionary format:

```
import pika

# ....
my_msg = {}
my_msg["a"] = 1
my_msg["a"]["b"] = 2
channel.basic_publish(exchange="", routing_key="some_key", body=my_msg)
```

And an error I get:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

Note that I have plenty of `my_msg` and each of them has a few keys, so I need somehow to be able to send a list dictionaries to RabbitMQ.

How can I do that? Or are there other options?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to serialize your dictionaries into strings and send them over RabbitMQ.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4342176/471899)

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](https://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/channel.html#pika.channel.Channel.basic_publish), `body` should be a string.

You might try `body=json.dumps(my_msg)`