# is there a way to pass a json as a parameter in rabbitmq basic_publish function?

Tags: python, json, rabbitmq, mailgun, fastapi

i am trying to send json data, in which i used `fstring` to make the data dynamic. when pass it to the `basic_publish`, i get    `raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} ' TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`
i have checked other related questions but i cant seem to work around it, i read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342176/how-do-i-serialize-a-python-dictionary-into-a-string-and-then-back-to-a-diction)

here is my code

```
    # confuguring sender
    def connect_queue():                                                                     
        rabbitmq = pika.BlockingConnection(                                                         
            pika.ConnectionParameters("localhost")                                    
        )                                                                                             
        return rabbitmq
    
    def mail_pwd_sender():  
                                                                  
        conn = connect_queue()                                                                        
        channel = conn.channel()                                                                      
        channel.queue_declare(queue='mail_pwd_queue', durable=True)                                    
        channel.queue_bind(exchange='amq.direct', 
        queue='mail_pwd_queue')                              
        mail_pwd_queue = channel                                                                     
        return mail_pwd_queue

   

        data = {
            
          "url":f"https://api.mailgun.net/v3/{Domain_name}/messages",
          "auth" : ("api", f"{API_KEY}"),
          "from_" : {"from": "mailgun@xxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org"},
          "data" : {"to": [recipient_email],
                "subject": subject,
                "html" : html,
                "recipient-variables":json.dumps(
                {f{recipient_email}": {"password": f"{body}" }})}
                    }
   
        send_queue = mail_pwd_sender()
        send_queue.basic_publish(                                                        
            exchange='amq.direct',                                              
            routing_key='mail_pwd_queue',                                        
            body=json.dumps(data),                                                         
            properties=pika.BasicProperties(                                    
                delivery_mode=2                         
            )                                                                   
        )
```

Comment: Please do not post code as images, nobody is gonna type your code from an image.

Comment: resolved, any help?